# Is it wrong to use * when reseting Margins/Padding in CSS?

Tags: css, performance

Should the following be shunned, or praised for its simplicity?

For the record, I use it in every site I build, but I've noticed it's not present in many main-stream CSS-reset frameworks — is there a reason they don't use it too?

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Good question!  I've wondered this myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its best NOT to use it as it causes issues with form elements, especially input buttons and select boxes.

See [christianmontoya.com](http://www.christianmontoya.com/2007/02/01/css-techniques-i-use-all-the-time/)

Answer (score 2):

The universal selector can slow things down quite a bit, especially on some WAP browsers. Just think about it for a second: it matches *every single* element in the document tree.

Besides, for most elements, you'll go on and specify a margin/padding that is different from 0 anyway. As in, there's no point in resetting them for all elements to begin with.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this?  I've never noticed any performance problems when I've used it.

Comment: @Jeff: It's pretty widely known - you can look at the effect in firebug, see how many inherits are applied. * considered unsafe.

Comment: Here's a chart: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Something you definitely don't want to do is use relative sizes with the universal selector. Things get weird really quick if you do. ;-)

For a good baseline to work from, I'd recommend a tried and tested [reset stylesheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Answer (score 1):

I once did some performance testing between the * {margin:0;padding:0}, Eric Meyer's reset, the YUI reset and no CSS at all. The performance difference was negligible.

That said, I now use Eric Meyer's reset so I don't lose the formatting on input buttons which actually makes buttons easier to style cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to set the padding and margin of every single element, then there should be no problem with that selector.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particularly wrong with it. * is referred to as the "universal selector", and browser support for it is generally considered to be good, though IE does have some obscure bugs, as usual:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/universalselector#compatibilitysection

Answer (score 0):

I consider it an important first step in building my CSS layouts.  It removes a lot of the troublesome default styling of different browsers and allows me to get more browser-independent results.

Of course I couple it with IE's conditional comments to write IE-version-specific divs around my whole page, and use those to work with IE's bugs (as FF et. al. tend to be more accurate to CSS spec).

EDIT - and I've never noticed any performance problems with it.

Comment: +1: I use this as a mandatory first line (yes, compressed to one single line) in about every single stylesheet i write. It makes everything so much easier later on IMO.