# How to set all CSS values to their default?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get back default properties after applying a global CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581880/get-back-default-properties-after-applying-a-global-css-reset)

I want to set all CSS properties for an object to whatever the default value for that property is.

```
var element = this.get(0); // from jQuery
var props = [];
for (var prop in element.style)
    props.push(prop);
return;
```

I need to override an existing stylesheet is why.

e.g.:

```
display:default !important;
color:default !important;
border-radius:default !important;
line-size:default !important;
```

or

```
display:!important;
color:!important;
border-radius:!important;
line-size:!important;
```

*not just those styles. all styles

Comment: What do you think 'default' is? Every browser has their own default stylesheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [initial keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial) to restore the default value of a CSS property.

> The *initial* CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element. It is allowed on every CSS property and causes the element for which it is specified to use the initial value of the property.

To restore every property to it's initial value, you'll have to manually add every property to the element's `style` attribute with a value of "initial".

Comment: No IE support it seems. or Opera. And the [quirksmode test](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/initial.html) doesn't seem to work on Chrome either. Actually quirksmode claims that initial "isn't supported by any browser yet."

Comment: Which is quite surprising, since it's a CSS2 feature.

Comment: No, it's CSS3 [according to the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#common-keywords).

Comment: The initial value is not at all the same as the default value.

Comment: `default` is an unused reserved keyword in CSS3.

Comment: Also, the quirksmode test fails in IE9, FF, and Chrome, so either it's a bad test or the keyword really isn't implemented.

Comment: it worked but i was getting cock blocked by -moz-initial for about 20 minutes before i realized it. unfortunately this technique is only working for me in webkit.